# Stay at matching search result after escape

Tags: search

For years I unknowingly used some, shall we say, deviant distribution of vim that would stay at the location of the highlighted search result after hitting `<Esc>` in the middle of a search instead of jumping back to the original position.

I've tried for more than a year now to forget that muscle memory, but I cannot for the life of me stop pressing `<Esc>` once what I've typed in the search has taken me to the position I'm searching for.

Does anyone know a) how I can get that behavior back, b) what *nix distribution had a copy of vim that defaulted to this behavior?

Comment: If you use enter instead of esc it should work out of the box.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt like I said, I've tried teaching myself to do that. Muscle memory.

Comment: This should just be the default behaviour (like it is in most modern editors). Vim *has* a selection history – that's the perfect system to use to go back to your previous selection after searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option for this:
`set cpoptions+=x`

From `:help cpo-x`

```
    x   <Esc> on the command-line executes the command-line.
        The default in Vim is to abandon the command-line,
        because <Esc> normally aborts a command.  |c_<Esc>|
```

It is also the default vim behavior when `compatible` is set, and is the behavior of vi in distributions that ship the "real thing," such as Arch Linux.

Comment: That might indeed be it. And since I never use <ESC> to abandon the command line (ctrl+c only), this would probably fit the bill!

Comment: Oof, this is good answer but, by god, is it some bad UI design! That's a serious betrayal of how <Esc> works in pretty much every single program. It's even in the name of the damn key - "escape"!

Comment: @iono, worth pointing out `<esc>` is also how you leave insert mode, i.e. "commit" the text edit, so by that it isn't too surprising

Comment: @Mass thanks, that's interesting to learn! I was assuming Vim was writing to the buffer with every change in insert mode. I've just been hitting `<esc>z`, which is handy anyway as it preserves the "mistake" in the edit timeline just in case it wasn't actually a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can configure this in VIM (see `help incsearch`) but

https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim

may be an option (if it's not already included you could ask for or implement that feature).

Comment: I already use it :(

Comment: Why don't you open an issue or PR?