# Jump to selected word after a search in vim

Tags: search

I use / followed by word to be searched to search for a word in a document. However once I find the word pressing escape just takes me back to the cursor location which is at the beginning of the document, while the word I need is somewhere in the middle. Is there a shortcut key to jump to the location of the currently highlighted word after a word search?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: You could also try to include the `x` flag in 'cpo'.  See [Stay at matching search result after escape](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13615/17449).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just press "Enter"!

What you're seeing is the result of `set incsearch`, which will show you the results of the search incrementally as you type... But you won't move to the actual match until you *execute* the search, by pressing the "Enter" key.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't try this.

Comment: @user13267 I know the feeling... `incsearch` can be quite disorienting when you start using it... Takes a while to get used to it.